# Proving $\Bbb Z_p$ has no projective cover.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

I need to prove that $\mathbb Z_p$ has no projective cover when seen as a module over $\mathbb Z$. I would appreciate your help.

A projective cover of $M$ is a projective module $P$ along with a surjective morphism $f:P\rightarrow M$ so that the kernel of $f$ is superfluous in $P$.

I'm not sure how to proceed. Since $\mathbb Z$ is PID the projective cover would have to be free, so of form $\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I}\mathbb Z$. And I think that the only options for the kernel are $p\mathbb Z+\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I,i\neq j}\mathbb Z$. Which is clearly not superfluous in the whole free module.

I think this "proof" can be vastly improved (even if we assume it is correct).

Comment: It is  a cyclic group of prime order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be a projective cover of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, $n\ge2$, and $f:P\to\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ a surjective homomorphism of $\mathbb Z$-modules. Then $P/\ker f\simeq \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. But $\ker f$ is superfluous in $P$, so for any other submodule $H\subset P$ from $\ker f+H=P$ we get $H=P$. It follows $\ker f\subseteq J(P)=PJ(\mathbb Z)=0$. ($J(P)$ denotes the Jacobson radical of $P$.) Thus $f$ is an isomorphism, so $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is a free $\mathbb Z$-module, a contradiction.

Comment: This proof shows that only the *free* $\mathbb Z$-modules have a projective cover.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I think I can modify this so it doesn't speak about the Jacobson radical and talk about the Socle instead (which is what we have seen in class).

Comment: I found a very similar argument. The kernel must be maximal (when $n$ is prime). A superfluous maximal submodule is a maximum submodule (contains every proper submodule). However projective modules over PID do not have maximum submodules (since they are free).